# Python Requests Code 141 Error

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to use requests in python to post a json dictionary to a url. I need to get a string back from the url but I keep getting a code 141 error -{"code":141,"error":"Missing a github repository link"}.  I'm using this website(http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/) to do requests.

Any ideas on why I keep getting that error? Code is below.

```
import requests
import json

payload = { "email" : "jade@gmail.com", "github" : "https://github.com/"}
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', "Accept": 'application/json'}
r = requests.post("http://challenge.code2040.org/api/register", params = payload, headers = headers)

print(r.url)
print r.text
```

Update: The suggestion worked but now I'm getting an{"code":141,"error":"success/error was not called"} error when I try to save the response I recieve from the url into a variable and then post it back to a different url.

```
#Store the token into a variable
token = r.text

payload = { "token" : token}
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', "Accept": 'application/json'}
r = requests.post("http://challenge.code2040.org/api/getstring", json = payload, headers = headers)

print r.text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are making a `POST` request and [you need to provide a JSON in the request body](http://challenge.code2040.org/), use [`json` argument](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/?highlight=post#requests.post), not `params`:

```
r = requests.post("http://challenge.code2040.org/api/register", 
                  json=payload, 
                  headers=headers)
```

<sup>(tested - got back a token)</sup>

Note that `json` argument was introduced in [requests 2.4.2](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/HISTORY.rst#242-2014-10-05).

Comment: The url I'm posting to returns a dictionary with two keys, for example say they are called "result1" and "result2"
How can I print out just the value of "result2?" Print r.text prints out all of the values.

Comment: @user2466886 use `r.json()` method to get the python dictionary.

Comment: Thanks but I'm getting the error, {"code":141,"error":"success/error was not called"}. Code  below:

    token = r.text

    payload = { "token" : token}
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', "Accept":     'application/json'}
r = requests.post("http://challenge.code2040.org/api/getstring",    json = payload, headers = headers)

   print r.text